# python class on html button click

Tags: python, html, django, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm totally new to all this python things, I've searched on my problem but withiout results, so I count on your help guys :)

I have a template file with button:

```
<button class="btn" value="{{invoice.number}}">Send</button>
```

In different file I have a class which runs function from another file:

```
class ReminderManual(webapp2.RequestHandler):
...
    for inv in invoices:
        is_send = reminder.send(inv)
```

And I'd like to:

1. run this class when the button is pushed
2. display is_send value

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: You can do without javascript and jquery using a form. In the app engine python tutorial you can find an example and explanation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to reload the complete page to get the result, you could to the following using JQuery and Ajax:

In HTML, you have

```
<button class="btn" value="{{invoice.number}}" id="myButton">Send</button>
```

and later in the file (before the closing `</body>` tag):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myButton').on('click', function (e) {
            var invoice_number = $('#myButton').val();
            var data = { invoice_number:invoice_number };
            var args = { dataType: "json", type:"POST", url:"/my_ajax_url/",
                        data:data, complete:ajax_call_complete };
            $.ajax(args);
        });
    });
    var ajax_call_complete = function(res, status) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(res.responseText);
        // use data as a json response object here and
        // do something with the response data
    }
</script>
```

In Javascript, the `/my_ajax_url/` would be the URL on which your request handler on the server runs. It is called via Ajax, the parameters are provided as POST parameters (in the code example, the value of the button is send as parameter `invoice_number`).

I typically set up my server Ajax requests to return JSON, which is then handled by the callback method (in the example, `ajax_call_complete`). Here you can check for errors and indicating the result to the user by displaying a message, modifying certain HTML elements, etc.

If you want to submit the complete page instead of using Ajax, you should use the Django forms mechanism:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/

Comment: That is a great answer.  But, is the idea to take a novice question, and completely write their code for them?  Just wondering.  But, +1 for the great answer

Answer (score 0):

The button needs an onclick handler, so it knows what to do.  The onclick handler is a javascript function that sends a new request via a url.  So, your app needs to handle that url, and execute the Class when a request comes to the url.

With jquery, you could easily make the onclick handler process an Ajax request to the url, and respond back with the value of is_send.  Still need a url handler in the app, which calls the class.

I see you added django as a tag.  With django, you could make the button part of a form, and use django's form handling to execute the class, and push back the value of is_send.